# Merging a branch into master but limiting your commits

Tags: git

```
                     feature-branch----C---D
                    /
     develop---A---B
    /
 master
```

I have a branch `feature-branch` that has been merged off a branch `develop`.  This develop branch is an ongoing branch that is merged into master weekly.  I've completed work on this feature-branch that is decided after the fact that it needs to go directly into master.  I don't want commits A and B that are in develop to go into master though.  Is there a nice solution that will allow me to get commits C and D into master without cherry-picking them?

Thanks,

Braden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rebase `feature-branch` onto master, removing its dependencies on commits A and B. If C and D have real, code-level semantic dependencies on A and B, then of course you are out of luck.

The following sequence of commands will modify `feature-branch` to be based off of `master` instead of `develop`:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase --onto master develop
```